# Google Analytics API (PHP) pull data from second property

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

For a particular website in my Google Analytics account, two properties are registered for the same website. Don't know who set it up like this first, but for now the first one has data from, say, 2010 to 2012, and the second has 2013 onward. I want to access the second property. Here's what the reporting page looks like (names smudged out):

[image]

By following the official tutorial for PHP, I'm able to access the first account and display its total sessions. But I'm not able to access the second account. I thought I'd change the following function:

```
function getFirstprofileId(&$analytics) {

    $index = 0;
    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($accounts);
    echo "</pre>";

    if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[$index]->getId();

        $webproperties = $analytics->management_webproperties
        ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($webproperties->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $webproperties->getItems();
            $firstWebpropertyId = $items[$index]->getId();

            $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
            ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstWebpropertyId);

            if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
                $items = $profiles->getItems();
                return $items[$index]->getId();

            } else {
                throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No webproperties found for this user.');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
    }
}
```

The `$index = 0;` thing you see is what I did, thinking that just by changing $index to 1 or something, I'll be able to access the next property, but it throws me an error saying `Call to a member function getId() on a non-object` on the code `$firstAccountId = $items[$index]->getId();`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What tutorial are you following exactly?  Any reason you aren't using Account Summaries report instead of making all these calls?

Comment: @DaImTo This one: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api. No idea how else to do it. Could you please, please, please point me to a useful resource? Even a book will do.

Comment: I thought as much.  That Tutorial uses the old client lib I have request that it be updated repeatedly.  Google didn't update it so I have.   http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/

Comment: P.S.: I'd LOVE to avoid OAuth and pull data straight from the script. Any tutorials you recommend?

Comment: That's why I gave you that.  You are after access to your own data. Use a service account instead of normal Oauth2.  make sure to give the service account email address read access at the ACCOUNT level in your google analytics admin.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks a ton! I was writing that comment as you were yours, so bit of a timing issue. I'll go through this and get back. Many thanks, again! :)

Comment: @DaImTo I followed your tutorial and even though I'm added with read access, I get the following exception: `Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries: (403) User does not have any Google Analytics account.`
Any idea why that might be happening, or should I post a new question and tag you?

Comment: I added a picture to the tutorial. To show you what it looks like.  By the message you posted I can say that you haven't added the service account email address to Google Analytics.  It must be at the account level.  Not web property or profile. (don't ask me why)

Comment: @DaImTo Looks like this is where I'm going wrong. I need to add the email ID generated in the console, whereas I thought having my official email address added to the account will do. Will try it out!

Comment: Try and think of a Service account as another person.  Evil co-worker that needs access, but really doesn't know what they are doing.  That is a service account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is probably related to the fact that you are using an old tutorial. Which uses Oauth2 and the old PHP client lib.  Because you are only trying to access your own data I recommend you go with a service account.

The current php client lib can be found on github:  [Google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Below is the code from my tutorial on using a service account with php to access Google Analytics Data.

```
session_start();        
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';        
/************************************************   
 The following 3 values an befound in the setting   
 for the application you created on Google      
 Developers console.         Developers console.
 The Key file should be placed in a location     
 that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
 web root.       web root.

 In order to access your GA account you must    
 Add the Email address as a user at the     
 ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin.         
 ************************************************/
$client_id = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$Email_address = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp@developer.gserviceaccount.com';     
$key_file_location = '629751513db09cd21a941399389f33e5abd633c9-privatekey.p12';     
$client = new Google_Client();      
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);    
// seproate additional scopes with a comma   
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";  
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(    
 $Email_address,         
 array($scopes),        
 $key        
 );     
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
 $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);      
}       
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();
//calulating start date  
$date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));     
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));    
//Adding Dimensions
$params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:userType'); 
// requesting the data  
$data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:78110423", $date->format('Y-m-d'), date("Y-m-d"), "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );  
?><html>     
<?php echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . " - ".date("Y-m-d"). "\n";?>    
<table>  
<tr>     
<?php    
//Printing column headers
foreach($data->getColumnHeaders() as $header){
 print "<td>".$header['name']."</td>";      
}       
?>      
</tr>       
<?php       
//printing each row.
foreach ($data->getRows() as $row) {        
 print "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";      
}    
//printing the total number of rows
?>      
<tr><td colspan="2">Rows Returned <?php print $data->getTotalResults();?> </td></tr>     
</table>     
</html>
```

Make sure that you give the `service account email address` access at the `Account` level in Google Analytics.

Code ripped from the tutorial:  [Google Service account PHP](http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/)

Comment: I've as you said, and I'm getting the following exception: `(403) User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile`. The project was created by the admin account, the service account was created by the admin account with read/analyze access, the Consent Screen was properly set up, and yet this. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/qCvF1sqA
Sorry to be bothering you again and again. :(

Comment: ga:78110423" <-- put in your own profile id and not mine :)

Comment: Doh! I feel like an idiot. It works now! Can't thank you enough!!!!!! :D :D :D :D :D

Comment: np adding the screen shot improves the tutorial for others. I will add a little note about the profile ID as well :)

Comment: Yes, please! And do mention how to get the profile ID. I happened to already know it, but this is another hair-pulling "feature" of the API. :D